# List.type does not take any parameters

Tags: scala

so I'm new to Scala and I wanted to practice some data structure stuff, but every single time I try to make a list, Scala is giving me an error. I don't have a main method defined yet, but I doubt that's the issue. Here's my code:

```
package dataStructures

object List {
  def listExample(): Unit = {
    //Creates new array of ints
    var list: List[Int] = List(2,3,4)               
  }    
}
```

What's so wrong about it?

Comment: You have named your own object `List`, the same name as Scala's standard `List`. Give it a different name, otherwise the compiler will use your own `List` instead of the standard one. For example: `object MyList { ...`

Comment: Oh, my bad I didn't realize that was important! Thanks!

Comment: PS: off-topic but important note. A **List** is not an **Array**.

Comment: Yeah, an array is a fixed size which I think means that it's inmutable while a list isn't fixed.

Comment: Think there is a misunderstanding. `List` is immutable/fixed size by default in Scala. P.S. Use `val` rather than `var`, also to avoid mutability.